# Getting a LoadError when using nokogiri gem in my ruby on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, require

When I put in a require statement to load the nokogiri gem I get a load error: *no such file to load -- nokogiri*

**requires:**

```
  require 'rubygems' 
  require 'nokogiri'
```

**gemfile:**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
source 'http://gems.github.com'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
gem 'rubygems'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2'

gem 'json'

# HTML Parser
gem 'nokogiri'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Also I am using ruby v1.8

Comment: Where did you put the "require" ?

Comment: Also, be careful with rails3/ruby1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem as you, but at last, I didn't need those "require" to make it work.

The problem I was having was that I didn't restarted the Application after installing nokogiri. Once I restarted the app, nokogiri worked just fine without those 2 "require" lines. The only "require" I needed at last was the "open-uri" because I was trying to scrap a remote page.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you did put the `require 'nokogiri'` inside the config/boot.rb. That's not the place, to do that.

Put it just at beginning of the file where you want to use it, or in an initializer or so.